# scipy minimize returns initial value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimization

I am trying to use scipy.minimize to perform a simple minimization (a basic example of simulated maximum likelihood). For some reason it just returns the initial value. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Simulated likelihood function
# Arguments:
# theta: vector representing probabilities
# sims: vector representing uniform simulated data, e.g. [0.43, 0.11, 0.02, 0.97, 0.77]
# dataCounts: vector representing counts of actual data, e.g. [4, 10, 7]
def simLogLikelihood(theta, sims, dataCounts):

        # Categorise sims using theta
        simCounts = np.bincount(theta.cumsum().searchsorted(sims))

        # Calculate probabilities using simulated data
        simProbs = simCounts/simCounts.sum()
        # Calculate likelihood using simulated probabilities and actual data
        logLikelihood = (dataCounts*np.log(simProbs)).sum()

        return -logLikelihood


# Set seed
np.random.seed(121)

# Generate 'true' data
trueTheta = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.5])
dataCounts = np.bincount(np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], 1000, p=trueTheta))

# Generate simulated data (random draws from [0, 1))
sims = np.random.random(1000)

# Choose theta to maximise likelihood
thetaStart = np.array([0.33, 0.33, 0.34])
bnds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  x.sum() - 1.0})

result = minimize(simLogLikelihood, x0=thetaStart, args=(sims, dataCounts), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
```

(The bounds in `bnds` reflect the fact that probabilities need to be between zero and one. The constraint in `cons` is that the probabilities have to sum to one.)

If I run this code, `result` contains:

```
     fun: 1094.7593617864004
     jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 5
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 0.33,  0.33,  0.34])
```

So it just does a single iteration and returns the vector of probabilities I started with. But it is easy to find another vector of probabilities with a lower objective, e.g. [0.1, 0.4, 0.5]. What is going wrong?

Comment: Thanks sascha for noticing my incorrect references to numpy rather than scipy. These have been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Your optimization-problem looks pretty **non-smooth** (probably because of `np.bincount()` but i'm not going to deep into it), which is really a bad thing for most optimizers there. As you also got constraints, you are left with only 2 optimizers (SLSQP, COBYLA), both assuming smoothness.

Adding a print like:

```
print(theta, -logLikelihood)
```

to `simLogLikelihood` at the end shows you, that during numerical-differentiation (as you did not provide a gradient), scipy is trying some small perturbations, but the objective is not changing at all (non-smooth)!

```
[ 0.33  0.33  0.34] 1094.75936179
[ 0.33  0.33  0.34] 1094.75936179
[ 0.33000001  0.33        0.34      ] 1094.75936179
[ 0.33        0.33000001  0.34      ] 1094.75936179
[ 0.33        0.33        0.34000001] 1094.75936179
     fun: 1094.7593617864004
     jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 5
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 0.33,  0.33,  0.34])
```

Although num-diff could be tuned to take bigger steps, i don't think your problem is a good fit here!

Quick demo (not recommended):

```
result = minimize(simLogLikelihood, x0=thetaStart, args=(sims, dataCounts),
              method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons, options={'eps': 1e-2})
                                                             # much bigger num-diff steps
```

Output:

```
[ 0.  0.  1.] inf
[ 0.21587719  0.2695045   0.51461833] 1013.80776084
[ 0.23010601  0.28726799  0.48262602] 1012.05516321
[ 0.23627513  0.29496961  0.46875527] 1010.48916647
[ 0.2386537   0.29793905  0.46340726] 1010.13774627
[ 0.23957593  0.29909039  0.46133369] 1009.0850268
[ 0.2397671   0.29932904  0.46090387] 1008.96044271
[ 0.23981532  0.29938924  0.46079545] 1008.96044271
[ 0.23983943  0.29941934  0.46074124] 1008.96044271
[ 0.23985149  0.29943439  0.46071414] 1008.96044271
[ 0.23985751  0.29944192  0.46070058] 1008.96044271
     fun: 1008.960442706361
     jac: array([ 947.81880269,  -52.71300484,    0.        ])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 44
     nit: 6
    njev: 5
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 0.23985751,  0.29944192,  0.46070058])
```

You see, that in some cases there are non-finite values returned by your function. Something very bad too!

So i highly recommend trying to formulate something smooth, not tuning the optimizers!