# Scipy minimization returns initialization values for discrete score function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy-optimize

I perform the following stochastic simulation study for a Hawkes process;

I have an n-dimensional vector D<sub>True</sub>  and a sampling process generated by 5 parameters, X = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}. Based on the 5 parameters X, I sample an n-dimensional vector D<sub>Sim</sub>. As a score, I sort D<sub>True</sub> and D<sub>Sim</sub> and take the absolute elementwise difference.

X has to satisfy a nonlinear constraint, which makes sure the sampled alpha matrix is stable. I used Scipy's 'SLSQP' method because 'L-BFGS-B' can not handle constraints.

My code now becomes

```py
import numpy as np

from tick.hawkes import SimuHawkesExpKernels
from scipy.sparse import rand
from scipy.spatial.distance import cityblock

n_nodes = 10  #dimension of vector D
D_true  = sorted[1797, 495, 7167, 4570, 8482, 5547, 524, 551, 525, 3490]) 

def distance(D_true, D_sampled):
    return 1/len(D_true) * cityblock(D_true, D_hat)

def simulate_alpha(n_nodes, k_r, theta_r, k_u, theta_u, gamma):
    
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed = 332)

    u = rng.gamma(k_u, scale = 1/theta_u, size=(n_nodes, n_nodes))
    r =  rng.gamma(k_r, scale = 1/theta_r, size=(n_nodes, n_nodes))

    beta = gamma + u
    alpha = beta + r
    return alpha

def simulate_D(alpha, n_nodes = 10, end_time = 1000):
    decays = 5 * np.ones((n_nodes, n_nodes))
    baseline = 0.5 * np.ones(n_nodes)
    hawkes = SimuHawkesExpKernels(adjacency=alpha, decays=decays,
                                  baseline=baseline, verbose=False, end_time = end_time, seed=2398)
    dt = 0.1
    hawkes.track_intensity(dt)
    hawkes.simulate()
    
    simulated_D = = sorted([len(hawkes.timestamps[i]) for i in range(hawkes.n_nodes)])
    return simulated_D

score = lambda x: distance(D_true, 
                           simulate_D(simulate_alpha(n_nodes, x[0], x[1], x[2], 
                           x[3], x[4]))

stability_eq = lambda x: abs(eigvals(simulate_alpha(n_nodes=n_nodes,
                                                    k_r=x[0],
                                                    theta_r=x[1],
                                                    k_u=x[2],
                                                    theta_u=x[3],
                                                    gamma=x[4]))).max()

stability_constr = NonlinearConstraint(stability_eq, 0, 1)

x0 = [0.01, 0.06 * n_nodes, 0.01, 0.06 * n_nodes, 1 / (4*n_nodes)]

res = minimize(fun = score,
               x0=x0,
               method='SLSQP',
               constraints=stability_constraint,
               tol = 10)
```

However, when running the code, the optimizer finishes after 1 iteration and returns the initialization value x0, although convergence is not reached (as the score equals 2250.5).

The output of `scipy.minimize` is as follows:

```
fun: 2250.5
     jac: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 6
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.01 , 0.6  , 0.01 , 0.6  , 0.025])
```

I tried different solvers, however as the optimization problem is non-smooth, we can only use SLSQP and COBYLA (see [scipy minimize returns initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004736/scipy-minimize-returns-initial-value))

Furthermore, I tried different initialization values `x0`, however, I still obtained the initialization values `x0` as a solution.

Comment: Please replace the output image with copy-pasted output. Images can be unreadable (especially for visually impaired people).

Comment: I'd avoid naming the lambda function and the actual function called inside the lambda both `score`.

Comment: fixed both comment

Comment: This isn't a **reproducible** example that we can copy-and-paste. For instance, `f`, `D_true` and `simulate_D` are still missing.

Comment: @joni thanks for your comment. The question was indeed incomplete. I added the missing parts.